# What is the mass required for a star to have the gravity equivalent to a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, mass, speed-of-light, stars

At what mass does the light from stars ( I am talking about stars and not black holes) fail to escape the star's gravity? Is it the same (minimum) mass required for an object to be called a black hole?

Comment: It is not about mass, but about density. 
**Any mass**, packed densely enough, will have an event horizon outside itself, which would make it into a black hole. This even goes for extremely small masses (I don't know if there is a theoretical lower limit due to quantum effects).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a name for the lower density limit?

Comment: Related, probably duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/is-there-some-special-cutoff-density-after-which-spacetime-collapses-and-forms

Comment: @Thriveth your density comment is really no more accurate than assuming it needs a certain mass.  You can form a black hole with any density you want given you have enough mass and enough volume.

Comment: @BrandonEnright But we agree that for a given mass, there i one, and just one, critical density, right? I don't really think I wrote anything else.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you can neglect quantum effects, *any* mass $M$ compressed to a sphere with radius less than its [Schwarzschild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius),
$$ R_\mathrm{S} = \frac{2GM}{c^2}, $$
will form a black hole. Now one should be careful about what the mass is, given that compressing an object can change its (gravitational, not baryonic) mass, but that's a minor point. For concreteness, if the Sun were compressed to a radius of less than $3\ \mathrm{km}$, it would be a black hole.

You can easily calculate a critical density<sup>1</sup> at which a uniformly dense sphere will have a radius smaller than $R_\mathrm{S}$. There isn't really another name for this, and "critical density" works pretty well, since it's analogous to the [same term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_density_%28cosmology%29#Density_parameter) used to describe the density of the universe where it is neither positively nor negatively curved.

Finally, if light cannot escape due to gravity, the object is by definition a black hole. There is no non-black hole equivalent.

---

<sup>1</sup> A term used everywhere in physics.