# Why do supermassive black holes have a much lower density then smaller ones?

Tags: black-holes

If at the centre of a supermassive black hole resides a singularity point which just continues to consume everything around it, then why is this black hole allowed to get larger and larger? Why is this mass not getting pulled into the singularity? All this millions of km of space from the singularity point to the edge of the black hole, why is it not getting smaller?

Comment: And I realise there's 2 separate questions that I have asked in this but would love some help with this, thanks guys :) !

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/5908/123208

Comment: Why do you think a black hole should get smaller? When people talk about the size of a black hole, they're (usually) talking about the size of its event horizon, the mathematical surface where the escape velocity equals the speed of light.The circumference of the event horizon is proportional to the BH's mass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can super massive black holes have a lower density than water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/how-can-super-massive-black-holes-have-a-lower-density-than-water)